# Spring web annation for controller

Tags: spring

I need to migrate a Spring web application to annotation.

It is using SimpleUrlHandlerMapping + ParameterMethodNameResolver, so url will be /myjob.do?cmd=addNew . what is the easiest way to convert it to Annotation ? is it something like this ?

```
@RequestMapping("/myjob.do?cmd=addNew")
public ModelAndView addNew(....) throws Exception {
}
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have more than one cmd value:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/myjob.do")
public class MyController {

@RequestMapping(params = "cmd=addNew")
public ModelAndView addNew(....) throws Exception {
 }
}
```